# Right using 'don't have to' and 'mustn't'

Tags: grammar

> I don't have to get up early. I have a day-off.

Why is it a mistake if I say: I mustn't get up early?

Comment: *I Do not have to*, means *It is not required of me*.  *I must not,* means, *It is forbidden for me (or by me)*.

Answer (score 3):

*I mustn't get up early* suggests that someone has told you "You *must* stay in bed late tomorrow". Obviously this isn't the case; it's just that you may do so if you want to.

I don't have to = it will be OK if I don't.

I must not = it will not be OK if I do.

Comment: @EllieK Well spotted - corrected.